# ReactiveTest: test a timeout on an observable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, timeout, reactive

I'm trying to use the `Microsoft.Reactive.Testing.ReactiveTest` to test an observable that should throw a timeout exception.

I can't find a way to have the timeout appear. The test always terminate with an empty `res.Messages`

Here is the code under test :

```
public class DeviceHandler : IDeviceHandler
{
    public readonly TimeSpan DISCOVER_SERVICE_TIMEOUT = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);    
    public IObservable<IGattService> DiscoverService(IDevice device)
    {
        return device
                 .GetKnownService(SERVICE_UUID)
                 .Timeout(DISCOVER_SERVICE_TIMEOUT);
    }
}
```

Here is the test code :

```
public class DeviceHandlerTest : ReactiveTest
{
    private DeviceHandler deviceHandler;

    private TestScheduler scheduler;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        deviceHandler = new DeviceHandler();
        scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldErrorIfNoServiceFound()
    {
        // GIVEN
        var mockDevice = new Mock<IDevice>();
        var mockService = new Mock<IGattService>();


        var mockServiceObservable = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(new Recorded<Notification<IGattService>>[]{
        });
        mockDevice.Setup(device => device.GetKnownService(deviceHandler.SERVICE_UUID))
            .Returns(mockServiceObservable);

        // WHEN
        var res = scheduler.Start(() => deviceHandler.DiscoverService(mockDevice.Object));
        scheduler.Sleep(20000); // I expect this to enable the timeout to trigger

        // THEN
        Assert.IsTrue(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(res.Messages, new Recorded<Notification<IGattService>>[] {
            OnError<IGattService>(100, new TimeoutException())
        }, new RecordedComparer<IGattService>()));
}
```

When I call `scheduler.Sleep(20000)` (20 seconds, which is superior to the 10 seconds timeout) I expect the timeout to trigger.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks